# Fast sum of values in a multidimensional array (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum

With a 1D array, I can use the sum method to get the sum of all the values.

```
int[] array = {6,3,1};
Console.WriteLine(array.Sum());
```

With a multidimensional array (3D in my case), this can't be done. Obviously I could go all foreach on it, but this seems verbose and I suspect it will perform badly.

Is there a way to flatten the array? Or a nice way just to get the sum that I've not seen?

Comment: What version of VS/ dotNET are you using, Can you use LinQ?

Comment: @Luke Duddridge in prelinq era arrays didn't do sums

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sum does exactly `foreach`. There is no magic behind them. If you are so performance hungry use `for` instead of `foreach`. You can do this in parallel also, this operation can be easily parallelized.

Comment: Perhaps this should be a separate question, but how would I parallelize it? (Very new to C#...)

Comment: Check out this two links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163329.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/

Especially at the blog, you can download a bunch of samples (ParallelExtensionsExtras)

Comment: @Tom Wright it is one of the most famous parallel tasks just google "parallel sum computation C#" the basic idea is to divide array to parts and calculate sub-sums in parallel threads. PLINQ makes it even easier. But before you start optimizing something make sure that it is actual bottleneck

Comment: @Tom Wright - Depending on which version of C# you're using, you could use Parallel.ForEach: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx

Comment: when using single dimensional arrays, foreach is at most times optimized to a for loop automatically by the compiler, so there won't be a performance difference

Answer (score 4):

this'll do the trick.

```
var i = array.SelectMany(j => j).Sum()
```

you could parallelize this in .net 4 like this

```
var i = array.AsParallel().SelectMany(k => k).Sum();
```

Comment: Haven't benchmarked it but i think array.Sum(j => j.Sum()) should be faster and in no way less readable. SelectMany().Sum() has to move twice through the array (AFAIK), once to generate the new enumerable and again to calculate the sum (unless LINQ optimizes this, not sure about that).

Comment: sum takes and ienum so it will prolly keep a running total and loop trough it. so for every int selectmany delivers it will add it to the total so it will only go through everything once. But I haven't looked into it either.

Answer (score 2):

Why should a `foreach` perform badly? You have to read every value at least once to calculate the sum. There is no way around this (assuming "random" values, of course). So maybe there is a more beautyful way, but not a more performant one (speaking in terms of *Big O*).

Comment: I'm not sure but according to some microbenchmarks i've seen there can be a performace differences between them.

Comment: @Andrey, bassfriend: you are right, maybe you get more performant implementations, but all of them rely on looping over every single value. Microbenchmarking as well as parallelizing will probably help, but my point is that an algorithm with *foreach/for* has not a bad performance per se. Linq or what ever can not skip the step of looping over all values.

Comment: when using single dimensional arrays *foreach* is at most times optimized to a for loop automatically by the compiler, so there won't be a performance difference

Answer (score 2):

If you have a jagged array and would like clean code you could use

```
int[][] array = { new []{ 6, 3, 1 }, new []{ 6, 3, 1 } };
Console.WriteLine(array.Sum(i => i.Sum()));
```